# how to print Arabic characters and bar-code using Xamarin Android Bluetooth printer. the Printer model is Star L300

Tags: c#, xamarin, printing, xamarin.android, arabic

I have to develop an app for Android that connects to a Star L300 printer via Bluetooth, it works fine for English. But when I come to Arabic characters its print them incorrectly. I try various encode (UTF-8, UTF-7, UTF-32, ASCII, BigEndianUnicode) for outputstream when writing to the printer but unfortunately nothing works.

Furthermore, the barcode 
Any suggestion on how to print the barcode using the same Bluetooth printer(Star L300)?

Could you please help.
Here the Code I used...

```
var datastream = mmSocket.OutputStream;

//I tried two different ways but it's not working
byte[] byteArray1 = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("\nAlamer" + "\n\nBarcode: " + barcode+ "\nName: " + ItName+"\nPrice: "+Price+"\nUnit: "+Unit);

byte[] byteArray =Encoding.GetEncoding("UTF-8").GetBytes("Star Clothing Boutique\n" +"123 Star Road\n" +"City, هلا 12345\n" +"\n");

byte[] bb = Encoding.GetEncoding("ASCII").GetBytes("{BStar.");

//printing 1
datastream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
datastream.Write(bb, 0, bb.Length);
```

Here is the code I used for barcode printing

```
var barcodeWritter = new ZXing.Mobile.BarcodeWriter
{
    Format = ZXing.BarcodeFormat.CODE_128,
    Options = new ZXing.Common.EncodingOptions
    {
        Width = 700,
        Height = 200
    }
};
Bitmap barcodes = barcodeWritter.Write(Intent.GetStringExtra("Code") ?? string.Empty);
PrintImage(barcodes);
```

Comment: Not sure about the SM-L300, but other SMs in that low-end range support english and double-byte CJK character sets, you would need to look up that model's specification to see what it supports.. FYI: Their larger POS printers support downloadable fonts. FYI: You could convert the unicode string to a bitmap and print it via the Android StarPRNT SDK (`AppendBitmap(....)`). You can also look at the AppendInternational and AppendCodePage StarPrnt APIs but I do not ever remember seeing Arabic supported.

Comment: Have you read the docs?  There is built in support for barcode printing, and Arabic codepages as well.  http://www.starasia.com/Download/Manual/starPRNT_cm_en.pdf